# remove default tab selection and also add scrollTo effect

Tags: javascript, html, scrollto

var tabLinks = new Array();
    var contentDivs = new Array();

function init() {

```
   // Grab the tab links and content divs from the page
   var tabListItems = document.getElementById('tabs').childNodes;
   for ( var i = 0; i < tabListItems.length; i++ ) {
     if ( tabListItems[i].nodeName == "LI" ) {
       var tabLink = getFirstChildWithTagName( tabListItems[i], 'A' );
       var id = getHash( tabLink.getAttribute('href') );
       tabLinks[id] = tabLink;
       contentDivs[id] = document.getElementById( id );
     }
   }

   // Assign onclick events to the tab links, and
   // highlight the first tab
   var i = 0;

   for ( var id in tabLinks ) {
     tabLinks[id].onclick = showTab;
     tabLinks[id].onfocus = function() { this.blur() };
     if ( i == 0 ) tabLinks[id].className = 'selected';
     i++;
   }

   // Hide all content divs except the first
   var i = 0;

   for ( var id in contentDivs ) {
     if ( i != 0 ) contentDivs[id].className = 'tabContent hide';
     i++;
   }
 }
```

function showTab() {
        var selectedId = getHash( this.getAttribute('href') );

```
    // Highlight the selected tab, and dim all others.
    // Also show the selected content div, and hide all others.
    for ( var id in contentDivs ) {
      if ( id == selectedId ) {
        tabLinks[id].className = 'selected';
      contentDivs[id].className = 'tabContent ';
      } else {
        tabLinks[id].className = '';
        contentDivs[id].className = 'tabContent hide';
      }
    }

    // Stop the browser following the link
    return false;
  }
```

In the above javascript, am looking to add scrollTo method to tabListItems and also remove default tab selection (i.e., no tab is selected by default).

cheers
venkat

Answer (score 0):

// Assign onclick events to the tab links, and
// highlight the first tab
var i = 0;

for ( var id in tabLinks ) {
tabLinks[id].onclick = showTab;
tabLinks[id].onfocus = function() { this.blur() };
**if ( i == 0 ) tabLinks[id].className = '';
contentDivs[id].className = 'tabContent hide';
i++;**
}
bolded part is been tweaked..!!

that makes, to hide the content and also deselects the default tab!!

Someone should help me with adding scrollTo() method to tabListItems part!!!